# is there any first order circuit with a second order derivative of supply voltage in equation

Tags: capacitor, circuit-analysis, inductor

I wanted to check if there could possibly be any first order circuit but with a second-order-derivative of the supply voltage appearing in the circuit equation,

something like this for a capacitive circuit:

$$a * \frac{d(v)}{dt} + b * v = \frac{d^2(Vs)}{dt^2} + c * \frac{d(Vs)}{dt} + e * Vs$$

or like this for an inductive circuit:

$$a* \frac{d(i)}{dt} + b*i = \frac{d^2(Vs)}{dt^2} + c*\frac{d(Vs)}{dt} + e*Vs$$

or even a combination of a capacitor and an inductor.

where ***Vs*** is the supply voltage, and ***a,b,c,e*** are constants, and ***v*** is capacitor voltage and ***i*** is the inductor current.

thanks.

Comment: XY question alert.

Comment: @Andyaka nope, it's the actual raw question of mine :)

Comment: I'm not sure what a *raw* question means, but please provide some context. Can you summarize in a couple of sentences what  you're trying to do and why?

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev well, it's not gonna be a practical circuit, it's just a theoretical problem my teacher asked. I don't have any idea  if that has any practical uses at all. So I don't have any additional info on that just as you.

p.s. some classes right here are not really serving so much useful points. :(

Answer (score 2):

Does this circuit act as you want?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnGS1m.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm not sure (I don't know much about transistor circuits yet) but I wanted a circuit using caps/inductors if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a near solution for the equation, but it doesn't have the $$ + e * Vs$$ at the end, I'd be very grateful if anyone could help me with this part.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fn9snb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>